# How to use parallel file processing in scala?

Tags: scala, file, parallel-processing

Hi~ I have 200 files and I want to process parallel file(read and write) in scala.

So, I tried several methods.

First, I used `par` method to process parallel file.

Here is my code.

```
val path = new Path("[file directory path]")    //Here is 200 text files.
val fileSystem = FileSystem.get(new Configuration())
val status = fileSystem.listStatus(path)
status.par.foreach{x =>
val stream = fileSystem.open(x.getPath) //Each text file open.
def readLines = Stream.cons(stream.readLine, Stream.continually(stream.readLine))
readLines.takeWhile(_ != null).foreach{ line => 

        //I want to write several file in here using PrintWriter.

        val f = new File(outputName)
        if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()){
        out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(outputName), true))
        out.append(line+"\n")
        out.close
        }else{
        out = new PrintWriter(outputName)
        out.println(line)                  
        out.close
        }
}
}
```

When I run this code, I got a error "too many open files".

So, I change ulimit -n 1024 to 65536. But It's not worked.

Second, I used `Thread` method.

```
val path = new Path("[file directory path]")    //Here is 200 text files.
val fileSystem = FileSystem.get(new Configuration())
val status = fileSystem.listStatus(path)
    status.foreach{x =>
      val thread = new Thread{
        override def run{
            val stream = fileSystem.open(x.getPath) //Each text file open.
            def readLines = Stream.cons(stream.readLine, Stream.continually(stream.readLine))
            readLines.takeWhile(_ != null).foreach{ line => 

            //I want to write several file in here using PrintWriter.

            val f = new File(outputName)
            if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()){
            out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(outputName), true))
            out.append(line+"\n")
            out.close
            }else{
            out = new PrintWriter(outputName)
            out.println(line)                  
            out.close
            }
         }
      }
      thread.start
      Thread.sleep(50)
    }
}
```

It also gave me an error `"$$anonfun$main$2$$anonfun$apply$mcVI$sp$3$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$2$$anonfun$apply$4.apply"`.

What is the problem in my code?

Actually, I don't know what to take. I tried everything I knew.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're creating a `printWriter` per line of each of 200 files?

Comment: And does it work without the `par`?

Comment: Originally it worked without `par`, but It's slow.
So I tried to do parallel processing using `par` or `Thread`.

Comment: I'm not sure. but I agree with your first reply.